# Reason for red wire in switch box?

Tags: wiring, switch

BLUF: need help with what to do with a red wire from the panel.

I'm replacing a bedroom switch with a Kasa smart switch. The old switch didn't control anything (*previous owner must have removed the overhead fixture*), but I'm looking to connect the new switch prior to installing the fixture.

However I'm seeing that there is a black, red, white and ground wire coming from the wall. Both the red and black are hot. If it helps, this is connected to a tandem breaker.

What should I do with this red wire?

I don't quite understand its purpose here.

Here is a photo for reference (*capped for safety*):

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117894/discussion-on-question-by-jonathan-ng-reason-for-red-wire-in-switch-box).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  brightened the picture in Photoshop and confirmed there is only one /3 cable coming into this box.   That makes it 1 of 3 possibilities.

- The far "spur/loop" end of a 3-way switch complex.
- A modern "switch loop" which brings Always-hot, Switched-hot and Neutral (for smart switches).
- The ceiling box is *fan-rated* with an obsolete "switch loop", but with an extra wire for separate control of light and fan.

In the last 2 cases, the cables in the wall are the same; you get to decide which of the two it will be, by how you wire it in the ceiling.

This much for sure, we have to see the wiring up in the lamp box to know any more.  There is definitely at least one more cable up there.  We need to see how they are interconnected, and whether the box has a "Fan Rated" marking.

P.S. Make sure your smart switch has a UL, CSA or ETL listing.  We see a LOT of cheap junk flooding the flea-markety mail order channels like eBay, Banggood, DealExtreme and unfortunately Amazon has opened their site to the eBay gang.  The junk even ships with Prime because they opened their warehouses too.

### Edit:

Given that there is apparently no existing ceiling box, it is most likely a switched receptacle.  If there is no ceiling light the only other way to meet Code is a switched receptacle.  That greatly increases the likelihood of the second possibility.

Often, rooms are wired with red-white-black circling the room.  Black is always-hot, red is switched-hot and white is neutral. Most receptacles are punched down to black and white (always hot).  The switched receptacle is punched down to red and white.  It *was* uncommon to extend the /3 all the way to the switch until 2011, but hey, OK :)

Often, such an installation will use a "split" receptacle (tab broken off on the hot side) to allow each socket's hot to be fed from a different wire.  One socket gets red (switched) and the other gets black (unswitched).

This would also jibe with the observation that red and black are both hot.  Very often, a dumb novice comes along who is changing receptacles for aesthetic reasons. They don't even know tabs are a thing. So they don't look for broken tabs, and they don't break the tab off on the new recep.  *This has the effect of shorting black and red, making the switch ineffective.  The switch stops working, they shrug their shoulders and resign themselves to switching lights off at the floor lamp.*

So my working theory is you inherited the above situation.  You'll need to open up the receptacle boxes in the room and see what  you can see.  It may simply be a matter of snapping off the right tab.

Comment: I got the TP-Link Kasa smart switch, I've had good experiences with their other smart products and they're fairly well known. As far as your comments: so you're saying this 14/3 is coming from the ceiling box? Side comment: in other units in my HOA, I believe they have fans in the bedrooms. it's possible they closed up the ceiling but I haven't had a chance to cut into it yet and figure out where the box might be.

Comment: @JonathanNg Well, the box won't be *buried* - that's illegal.  You're not allowed to bury boxes.  I get where you feel like "I picked a well-reviewed product and I like it" - nobody's attacking your consumer skills here.  The only thing that matters is whether the product is certified by a recognized testing lab.  As for those reviews, just type the word  "brushing" into Google...

Comment: totally get that, I was just saying I picked a company I know, and as far as I can tell the product is certified. re: burying boxes - there's a chance that happened, which I know is a total code violation, but I can't say for sure what the previous owner did. in my testing, the switch does not control any receptacle in the room. any tips on how to trace where the 14/3 is going? barring ripping my walls down

Comment: *Oh wait, so there isn't a visible ceiling box??*  It's real common for builders to cut corners by not fitting any ceiling box at all, and just switch a receptacle.  You have to check **both** sockets of every receptacle in the room, because receptacles can be easily "split" so 1 socket is switched and the other is not.  Switching either an overhead light or a recep is a code requirement, so they must have done it.  Otherwise open up 1 recep at a time and see if the red wire shows up there.

Comment: I will have to pull out the receptacles - I was checking them by using a lamp and testing the switch each time I changed receptacles. and no, there is no visible box overhead - though there is a faint, 6in-ish wide line going from one end of the room to the other (as if it were a drywall patch job). that's the only reason I guessed a previous box was there. photo for reference: https://ibb.co/sJNrNrK

Comment: also wanted to add: when I opened it initially, the red and black wires were connected to the switch, but the neutral was capped off on its own. not sure what that means wrt everything we've discussed so far

Comment: @JonathanNg Interesting. That would suggest a "modern switch loop" with always-hot, switched-hot and neutral(white).  That would be good news indeed.  If indeed it was a switched socket, it's possible "the last owner" disliked this, and went into the receptacle box and jumpered it to be unswitched. That's a Code violation.  It's also possible it had a split recep, and someone changed the recep for unrelated reasons (e.g. aesthetics) and did not realise they needed to break off the tab.  That would unsplit it, shorting red and black, making both always-hot.

Comment: so what would you propose for a path forward? I tested each receptacle with a lamp, no dice. should I pull them out and look for the red wire? we can also move to a separate comms platform if you're available and willing (not sure how that works on this platform)

Comment: @JonathanNg I added an edit to my answer that describes the likely situation further.  Now it's just down to pulling the existing receptacles out and looking to see what you see. I suspect you'll find one or more  places where red and black both go to the hot side (brass screws) of the recep, yet, the tab is not broken off.

Comment: and if I break those tabs? how would I be able to get this wiring to now control an overhead fixture? sorry, I've only dealt with straightforward wiring. or, I can report back tomorrow when I get some time to pull receptacles from the wall

Comment: Good chance yes.  Any receps with red wire in the box, snap some pix and edit into your question.

Comment: I have found the red wire! a few comments: it looks like they snipped off the bare end of the neutral from the 14/3 and left it unhooked. it also looks like the black wire from BOTH the 14/3 and a separate 14/2 are connected to the top receptacle (one pushed in, one wrapped, unsure of legality here). finally, I don't believe the brass tab is broken. here is a photo: https://ibb.co/6bskkQt

Comment: update: since the tab is not broken, can I run new 14/2 to the switch box, then 14/2 to a new fixture? as in this link (first picture): https://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/images/wiring-outlet-to-switch-to-light.gif

Comment: @JonathanNg Yes, there's the tab that isn't broken off and needs to be broken off. I would just break that off!   You can run the cable to the new light from EITHER the recep location there, OR the switch, your choice.  You don't need to do both. On this new cable, mark the black wire with red electrical tape.  It will then hook up in the obvious manner.    As far as using 14/2, that's OK if the breaker handle says "15".  If it says "20" you must use 12/2.

Comment: so if I break the tab, then connect a fixture to that switch, the switch will control both the light and the recep, right? is it possible to keep the recep as always hot, and using the power from there to create the light fixture switch on its own loop?